# How to tell which WPF UserControl was clicked?

Tags: wpf, events, button, controls

I have a bunch of user controls with buttons on them stored in a listbox. Right now they all pass their button events to a main script and that prints "A button was clicked", it would be better though if it printed "Button D was clicked" as I need to store exactly which buttons were clicked in an array.

Answer (score 1):

The sender parameter in the event call refers to the sending button.

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button button = (Button)sender;
}
```

This might work if the first one does not:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Button button = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
}
```

here's a more generic approach if you only want the listboxitem

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    object context = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
    var lbi = lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(context) as ListBoxItem;
}
```

see posts: 
[How to select ListBoxItem upon clicking on button in Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720941/how-to-select-listboxitem-upon-clicking-on-button-in-template)
[How to retrieve sender in click handler from toolbartray or other control in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389710/how-to-retrieve-sender-in-click-handler-from-toolbartray-or-other-control-in-wpf)

Comment: it's not the sender. It should be the OriginalSource in the EventArgs

Comment: Is there any way to get the user control the button is inside of? I don't actually want the button as much as I want the user control's information.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use the CommandParameter of the button and reference that.